# ArcPy Calculate Field Management with Variable

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-3

I'm trying to calculate multiple fields that all begin with "B01". This calculation consists of multiplying the fields by a field that contains a percentage ("TractPercent") and then dividing the results of that multiplication by a population field ("BufferPOP").

The problem I'm having is incorporating the variable associated with my "for loop"  with my Python3 expression.

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy

### set workspaces
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\Demographics.gdb"
relpath = r'C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python'
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(relpath + r'\Demographics.aprx')
m = p.listMaps('Map')[0]

layers = m.listLayers("DalyCity_HalfMile_Demographics")  
for layer in layers:
    print(layer)

    DemoFields = arcpy.ListFields(layer, "B01*", "ALL")
    for DemoField in DemoFields:
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(layer, DemoField, "(+DemoField+ * 
        !TractPercent!) / !BufferPOP!", "PYTHON3")
        print(layer.name + ' ' + DemoField + ' Calculated')
```

When I run the code this way I get the following error, but can't figure out what I need to change.

```
ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Calculate Field). Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000623: Invalid value type for parameter field
```

Comment: What's the format of the DemoField? What happens if you add some print statements - are you getting the values you expect?

Comment: @smiller I added some print statements and they returned what I expected them to. As far as the format, the data type is "Double". Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: @MattA., could you give us an example of what the print statement returned? And I think smiller meant to print the expression itself. Did you try testing the result directly in the Field Calculator, not using ArcPy?

Answer (score 5):

Your expression shouldn't include variable names. You're writing:

```
"(+DemoField+ * !TractPercent!) / !BufferPOP!"
```

but it should be:

```
"(!{}! * !TractPercent!) / !BufferPOP!".format(DemoField.name)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `DemoField.name`?

Comment: I've tried both `"(!{}! * !TractPercent!) / !BufferPOP!".format(DemoField)` and `"(!{}! * !TractPercent!) / !BufferPOP!".format(DemoField.name)`, but I am still getting the same errors. I looked at the data types associated with the `CalculateField_management`, (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm) but didn't see anything that stood out. Except for maybe that `.format(DemoField)` is outside the quotes

Comment: Thanks, Bjorn. I always get a list of names with list comprehension, so I overlooked that. It's fixed. @MattA., it's supposed to be outside the quotes. Otherwise, you're simply looking for a field that matches your variable name rather than the value held by the variable.

Comment: @MattA., what are the datatypes of each of your fields?

Comment: @Tom I tried running the code in the Code Block of the Field Calculator and got a similar error about a missing or incorrect parameter. The datatypes for all the fields I'm using in the code is "Double". As far as the print statements, I was able to successfully print the the Table name and the DemoField name. I'm not sure how I would print the expression, unless I assigned it to a variable.